# Why does UIView animation only work with long durations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I've searched and saw this question asked before but still haven't found an answer sufficient for my needs.

I have an some UIImageViews in my view. They are stored in a NSMutableArray property called viewArray. However, when I run the following animation code, the UIImageViews just skip to their final state, without any animation. If I change the duration to 10.0, the animation works fine, but that's too long for my purpose.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                 animations:^{
                     for (UIImageView *view in viewArray) {
                         view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 1.5, 1.5);
                     }
                 }];
```

These UIImageViews are already in the view since I saw some answers that addSubview is not instantaneous so that's not the problem.

What exactly is going on? Is there something I need to keep in mind in designing animations?

Comment: I have an NSTimer that fires every second, but that only executes a very basic command on each fire (decrements an int).

Comment: Are you calling this from the main thread?

Comment: How many imageViews do you have in the for loop?

Comment: I tested this code with ~50 imageViews (I thought more was excessive) and it worked perfectly fine with one second.  Check for memory leaks and other expensive operations.

Comment: Agree with @AdamG: try running the same code with just a few views, and see if that works OK. If yes, then it's the number of views you're trying to animate simultaneously that's the problem.